# How to host a Blazor server app in a .NET MAUI BlazorWebView?

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, maui, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I have an existing Blazor server app that I created in Visual Studio using the *Blazor Web App* project template (Interactive render mode=Server, Interactivity location=Per page/component). I also have a *.NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid Web App* project in the same solution. I want to run the Blazor server app in a `BlazorWebView` control in the .NET MAUI app.

Now I need the MAUI app to use the Blazor App. So I have configured the Visual Studio to run both projects. I have made an (naïve) attempt to connect applications together. In `MainPage.xaml` in `BlazorWebView` component I have set `HostPage="https://localhost:7021/"` .
However, when I run the .NET MAUI app, I get an `ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID` error with the address `https://0.0.0.0/`. The Blazor server app runs fine on its own at `https://localhost:7021/`.

**Is it possible to host a Blazor server app in a .NET MAUI `BlazorWebView`?** If so, what am I missing or doing wrong?

**I am not looking for a solution with a generic web view.** I am currently not evaluating whether this approach is reasonable or not. I just want to know if it is feasible and how to do it.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is your end goal of trying to achieve that ? (maybe there is a better/easier approach)

Comment: From the doc [BlazorWebView.HostPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webview.windowsforms.blazorwebview.hostpage?view=net-maui-7.0),  the value should be the Path to the host page within the application's static files.

Comment: @Cfun: I have an existing Blazor Server application. I am just curious if (and how) I can use it with MAUI. The main reason is that I am planning to add new features to the application and integrate it with the mobile app part.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried MAUI myself, but you could try modifying your `appsettings.json` so that it starts the application where MAUI expects it to be (i.e., 0.0.0.0, port 80). Something like:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://0.0.0.0:80"
      }
    }
  }
}
```